# C# Throwing unable to resolve controller error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm fairly new to .NET and c# and I'm working on a POC where I've run into an issue when a controller throws the error

System.InvalidOperation Exception {"Unable to resolve controller: TenantController"}

The Inner exception details are

No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'GICS.Web.Managers.Interfaces.ITenantManager'

There is no configuration specified for GICS.Web.Managers.Interfaces.ITenantManager

1.) new TenantController(*Default of ITenantManager*, *Default of IRemedyService*)

2.) GICS.Web.Controllers.Api.TenantController

3.) Instance of GICS.Web.Controllers.Api.TenantController

4.) Container.GetInstance(GICS.Web.Controllers.Api.TenantController)

The TenantController looks as follows:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using GICS.Web.Controllers.Api.Abstracts;
using GICS.Web.Managers.Interfaces;
using GICS.Web.Services.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GICS.Web.ViewModels.Tenant;
using GICS.Web.Models.Tenant;

namespace GICS.Web.Controllers.Api
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/tenant")]
    public class TenantController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly ITenantManager _tenantsManager;
        private readonly IRemedyService _remedyService;
        private string token;

        public TenantController(ITenantManager tenantsManager, IRemedyService remedyService)
        {
            _tenantsManager = tenantsManager;
            _remedyService = remedyService;
            token = null;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("{groupId}/{userName}")]
        public JsonResult getTenants(string groupId, string UserName)
        {
            getToken(UserName);
            JsonResult result = Json(null);

            if (token != null)
            {
                var tenants = _tenantsManager.GetTenants(token, groupId);
                List<TenantViewModel> tenantViewModelList = new List<TenantViewModel>();

                foreach (Values x in tenants)
                {
                    TenantViewModel model = new TenantViewModel(x, groupId);
                    tenantViewModelList.Add(model);
                }
                result = Json(tenantViewModelList);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The TenantManager interface is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GICS.Web.Models.Tenant;

namespace GICS.Web.Managers.Interfaces
{
    public interface ITenantManager
    {
        IEnumerable<Values> GetTenants(string token, string groupId);
    }
}
```

And the Manager implementation is:

```
using GICS.Web.Managers.Abstracts;
using GICS.Web.Managers.Interfaces;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using GICS.Web.Models.Tenant;

namespace GICS.Web.Managers
{
    public class TentantManager : ManagerBase, ITenantManager
    {
        public IEnumerable<Models.Tenant.Values> GetTenants(string token, string groupId)
        {
            Tenant restEntries = null;
            List<Models.Tenant.Values> tenantList = new List<Models.Tenant.Values>();

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = token;
                var baseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemedyBaseUrl"];
                var apiPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RemedyAPIPath"];

                string getURL = baseURL + apiPath + "ESN%3AAST%3ALogSysComp%5FASTPeople" + "?q=?q=%27PeopleGroup%20Form%20Entry%20ID%27%20%3D%20%22" + groupId + "%22&fields=values(Name)";
                string getResponse = client.DownloadString(getURL);

                restEntries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tenant>(getResponse);

                foreach (Models.Tenant.Entry x in restEntries.entries)
                {
                    tenantList.Add(x.values);
                }
            }

            return tenantList;
        }
    }
}
```

I have other controllers in the project that follow the same approach and all are working except for this one. Anyone spot where I am going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to instruct your "IOC Container" to resolve that Interface with a provided Type.

Comment: You need to define the mapping ITenantManager->TentantManager . What DI framework are you using ?

Comment: I am using StructureMap